# Python subproccess.py FileNotFoundError when running as packaged binary, but not as pip package

Tags: python, path, package, subprocess, filenotfoundexception

I have this debug code snippet in my app:

```
files_path = pathlib.Path(appdirs.user_data_dir(appname="my_app"))
subprocess.run([
    "ls", "-la", files_path
])
```

My app can be run as a pip installed package, or you can download an executable built with `argparse`. When run as pip package, it works fine, but when using the executable, I get this error:

```
  File "subprocess.py", line 548, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1493, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

All my path structures use `pathlib` to ensure cross compatibility between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `files_path` exists? Try:

```
files_path = pathlib.Path(appdirs.user_data_dir(appname="my_app"))
print(files_path.exists())
```

If you need to create folder first:

```
files_path = pathlib.Path(appdirs.user_data_dir(appname="my_app"))
files_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
subprocess.run(...)
```